# How to access cypress.env file from another test file

Tags: cypress

I use `command.js` as a storage of common function.
here is the code for generating token:

```js
Cypress.Commands.add('get_token', () => { 
    cy.api({
        method: "POST",
        url:    "https://api-stg.sample.com/login",
        body: 
        {
        "mobile_number": 09123456789,
        "password": "p@ssw0rd"  
        }
      })
        .then((response) => {
          const token = response.body.data.access_token.token
          cy.log("Bearer token: " + token )
          
          Cypress.env('token', token)
      })
    })
```

on my test file , I tried to use the function `get_token` and use the generated token to put value on my headers: authorization

```js
      use_auth_from_commandjs () {
        cy.get_token() 

        cy.api({
          method: "POST",
          url:    "https://api-stg.sample.com/auth",
          headers: { 'Authorization': `Bearer ${Cypress.env('token')}`},
...
```

Why I cant access the `Cypress.env('token', token)` from my test file?
as per my understanding using `Cypress.env( )` sets the variable as global.

on my logs Bearer token is always as `undefined`.
 `"Authorization": "Bearer undefined",`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's subtle, but your `cy.api()` command is loading up the value of `Cypress.env('token')` before it's been set.

You can get around it by deferring the loading of the 2nd `cy.api()` command like this

```js
use_auth_from_commandjs () {
  cy.get_token() 
    .then(() => {   // using .then() means do next part after previous commands have run
      cy.api({
        method: "POST",
        url:    "https://api-stg.sample.com/auth",
        headers: { 'Authorization': `Bearer ${Cypress.env('token')}`},
        ..
    })
...
```